# Child window innerHTML displaying as text if sent via string variable

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am trying to create a web page that will enable a child window to display some additional text when a gridview row is double clicked.

I am grabbing the HTML text from a hidden column of the gridview and sending it through as follows :

```
Dim outputText As String = (e.Row.Cells(12).Text)

e.Row.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", "var openWindow = window.open('Child.htm','Ratting','width=550,height=170,0,status=0,');openWindow.document.getElementById('content2').innerHTML = '" + outputText + "';") 'openWindow.init();")
```

When the window pops up, the HTML is displayed as text - tags and all.

If I use the following and paste the same text within the code - rather than via the string, the HTML displays correctly.

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", "var openWindow = window.open('Child.htm','Ratting','width=550,height=170,0,status=0,');openWindow.document.getElementById('content2').innerHTML = " + chr(34) + "<img src='http://www.test.com/images/image%201.jpg'/><br/><br/>Some more text"+ chr(34) + ";") 'openWindow.init();")
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction please? I can't figure out what's wrong and it's been driving me mad.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out.

It seems when the text is posted via a variable, the tags < and > get replaced by '&lt' and '&gt'

So to fix it, I appended this after I set the innerHTML :

```
openWindow.document.body.innerHTML=openWindow.document.body.innerHTML.split('&lt;').join('<').split('&gt;').join('>');
```

And it's done the trick!